# Как вытащить полученое значение переменной из счетчика?

Tags: javascript, переменные, функции

Есть функция, которая подгружает переменную из файла:

```
function getSomeValue()
{

    var values = 0;  //значение по умолчанию

    response = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test2.php',
        async: false,
        data: {type:'request'},
        dataType: 'json',
    }).responseText;

    values = $.parseJSON(response);
    return values.response;

}
console.log(getSomeValue());
```

То есть мы получим значение переменной из другого файла в переменную `response`....но проблема в том что в другом файле, значение переменной изменяется несколько раз в 10 секунд там стоит счётчик, дак вот как мне обновлять значение переменной `response` ??

У меня была идея сделать счётчик:

```
setInterval(function() {

 getSomeValue();
document.write(response);
},  1000);
```

и всё получилось, но только слегка не так как я хотел. тут получается что значение `response` изменяется раз в секунду выводиться и у меня получается так на странице: `response1; response2; response3;` и так далее. но мне так не нужно....мне нужно чтобы переменная `response` обновлялась ...я знаю можно её последнее значение засунуть в `DIV` вот так `$("#div").text (response);` но проблема в том что мне не нужно выводить значение `response`  в див....мне нужно значение переменной `response` использовать в другой функции.

Уже пятый день бьюсь, гугл и яндекс мало чем помогли...рассчитываю на вашу помощь дорогие друзья.

Answer (score 1):

Что вам мешает сделать, например, так:

```
var currentResponse = 0;
setInterval(function() {

 currentResponse = getSomeValue();

},  1000);
```

Comment: currentResponse значение этой переменной выводиться - 0...я уже так пробовал..к сожалению не получается(

тут необходимо как то в счетчике результат выполнения функции присваивать в переменную а потом выводить её отдельно из функции